# Power spectra density for line code

Tags: digital-communications

Why do we need to find power spectra of different line codes? why we relate it to to the auto correlation of the signal? how does it help us in  transmission of digital signals?

Answer (score 1):

Digital data are stored in the form of bits, i.e: 0 and 1. The binary data is stored in memory cells usually as static charges (DC Voltage). When transmitting a series of binary bits, we need some sort of waveform to be able to send them on a specific channel. Line codes help us achieve the goal of transmitting the data over specific passband/baseband channels. Now, to be able to allocate resources such as bandwidth, power, etc, we need to know the spectral behavior of our **Transmitted Signal**. This signal is produced using a line code acting on a baseband signal. Therefore, we need to know the effect of the line code spectrum on the signal spectrum. Both of these spectra contribute to the final transmission spectrum, which is meant to be transmitted. Over the years, different line codes have aimed for bandwidth/power efficiency, as well as reduction/control of inter-symbol interference (ISI).

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said that the spectrum helps to estimate does the signal fit into the line.

But there's more. Extracting the right timing in the receiver is essential for optimal decision making. Peak in the spectrum makes it easier.

If there's several data lines it's possible that there's crosstalk. Knowing the transfer function of the crosstalk and the spectrum gives a possibility to estimate the effect of the crosstalk.

Data communication theory textbooks show how the power spectrum formula can be derived. The final formula can be divided to 3 major sections:

- the power spectrum of the used pulse
- the coding rule "how 1 and 0 are presented with the used pulse"
- data stream statistics

The statistics can be shown as discrete autocorrelation function in the spectrum formula.

If the data stream contains some periodic patterns the timing in the receiver can get distorted and the decision making isn't optimally timed. Autocorrelation function reveals the perodicity .

Answer (score 0):

To recover data, the stored energy (in the communication path) must be low enough that acceptable ISI Inter-Symbol-Interference results.

Narrow bandwidth ensures lots of ISI, and thus ensures lots of bit errors.

To design the communication system, the required bandwidth (for tolerable ISI and BER)
must be known.